# android how to get the statue of phone whether it is playing a sound file

Tags: android

A user make a new task A and set the alarm, then he make another new task B in the same time and also set the alarm.

When the alarm for task A come up,the user doesn't dismiss the alarm on time,the alarm for task B just come after it.Well,now it's duet.

I want some help for judge the statue if the phone is playing any music sounds or how to prevent the alarm to show duet.

My project must depend on API 7.

Comment: I tried.But this interface work for API 8. My project depends on API 7.

Answer (score 0):

To get the statue of phone whether it is playing a sound file, you can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) document.
Before your app starts playing any audio, it should hold the audio focus for the stream it will be using. This is done with a call to `requestAudioFocus()` which returns `AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED` if your request is successful.

Comment: oh my god.My project depends on API 7,the OnAudioFocusChangeListener interface was added in API 8. Do you have more idea?